# MySQL throws a warning when executing a "before delete" trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a small database ([SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edafe)) that I am designing.  I am trying to create a trigger so that when a row is deleted from `downtime`, a matching history line gets added to `downtimeHistory`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `announce`.`downtime_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `downtime` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO downtimeHistory (serviceName, startTime) VALUES(OLD.serviceName, OLD.startTime);
END
```

However, MySQL doesn't care for this trigger.  It allows me to create it, and it appears to be functioning correctly, but it throws an error each time the trigger is executed:

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly.
```

This would make sense to me if I were trying to do something with the `id` or `endTime` columns, but updating startTime shouldn't matter since it just provides a default value.

So...why is it throwing this error?  How do I stop it?  Should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger inserts into the downtimeHistory table.  The id column is AUTO_INCREMENT.

The error message tells you that this combination is not allowed.

The `INSERT INTO....` statement implicitly causes the ID value to be set.

Comment: Is there an alternative?  It technically works (it's inserting into `downtimeHistory` and auto-incrementing the `id` column appropriately).  Is there documentation outlining this?

Comment: I suppose you could always remove the ID column and just use a timestamp.

Comment: Removing the `id` column and setting the PK to be `serviceName` + `startTime` worked.

Comment: As an alternative to the trigger, you could also do the pair of operations in a stored routine or wrap them in a transaction.